# JXCore Cordova => Native Cordova Plugin (can't reach cordova.exec(...))

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, jxcore

I'm using the [JXCore Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova) to get my Node.js Application running on mobile devices. I also wrote a native cordova plugin, to process some tasks in native part of the application.

But I can't reach the native cordova plugin. Is this the right approach to do this?

**1. Register method from UI to jxcore instance** (*index.js*): 
 jxcore('someNativeExtension').register(someTriggerMethod); 
 
(where the trigger does something like cordova.exec(...);)

**2. Start Node** (*index.js*): 
jxcore('app.js').loadMainFile(callback); 
 
(after this step I move to another index.html, that is served by express.js: 
 
=> window.open('http://localhost:8080/apps/backend/index.html','_blank');)

**3. Call method from Node** (*app.js*): 
Mobile('someNativeExtension').call();

But this snippet doesn't work, because it seems, that cordova.js isn't present, after I receive another html file. Do you have Any Idea, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you browse another URL, cordova client side files are not loaded with that URL. Since you have the control for the loaded HTML page, that page can load cordova + jxcore JS files

Comment: Hey Nuray, that exactly is the point. I cannot load cordova or jxcore at my other (backend) HTML Page, because it is served by my Express.js server, which is running (deep) inside in of my jxcore directory. I can't reach cordova or jxcore (which are reachable via the file system on the android).

I did find out, that I can reach window._cordovaNative - but I'm not really sure, if this helps. Thank you anyway! Any Idea left? :D